# Okta as IDP in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We need to configure okta as IDP for azure ad applications. For example: When a user tries to access the enterprise application, they'll be challenged with a login page, which will be validated by OKTA. Post this authentication, the authorization will be handled by Azure and upon successful authorization, user will be shown a landing page of the application.

We have referred below links as reference for setup:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/direct-federation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp
https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/custom-url-domain/overview/

What we did so far?

1. Registered company "example.com" in okta. By default okta configures it as "example.okta.com"
2. Registered custom domain "id.example.com". Our okta instance is accessible using this domain
3. Created an enterprise SAML app (which also exist in Azure AD) in OKTA
4. Exported OKTA IDP metadata

Now, we are trying to import this IDP metadata as external identity provider in AAD. But it fails with below error, if we map example.com or id.example.com as domain name of federating idp. Because of these errors we’re unable to setup the custom domain of federated IDP(OKTA). ***Please assist us on the approach for the same.***

Error Messages:

For domain as "id.example.com"
Failed to add a SAML/WS-Fed identity provider.This direct federation policy does not pass one or more requirements. Go to aka.ms/b2b-direct-fed to learn more.

For domain as "example.okta.com"
Failed to add a SAML/WS-Fed identity provider.This direct federation configuration is currently not supported. The authentication URL must match the domain for direct federation or be one of the allowed domains. Go to aka.ms/b2b-direct-fed to learn more.

Comment: well, its really late reply but have you tried using custom domain in Okta? you can configure example.com or id.example.com as custom domain and don't need to use example.okta.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the [Azure AD federation compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-compatibility#idp-validation) to learn about how to federate an Azure AD tenant with a 3rd party IDP like Okta and others.

Comment: We have gone through the compatibility list. It supports okta.com but also expects domain to be example.okta.com. It directs to okta for authentication only if the user name to login to azure is user1@example.okta.com For example : If I login as user1@example.com it authenticates against AAD. In real time scenario the user will be user1@example.com only.

Comment: Hi @KajalChaudhari did you manage to get this working? I am looking at same scenario, Okta will be IDP for Azure, I want to use AzureAD username to login and then Okta should takeover authentication and return me to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

@Kalyan Krishna

Hi,
Thanks for the reply. We have already gone through the documentation. OKTA is listed down as one of the supported 3rd party federated IDP that Azure supports. We referenced the MS docs and tried to configure, but we observed Azure AD doesn't support external IDP(OKTA) configuration with **custom domain**. It throws error as mentioned in the above post. So, we tried to configure the federated domain as ".okta.com" (including other IDP metadata details). It worked then, and for authentication AZ AD is getting redirected to OKTA. SP authentication flow works fine when myapps URL is appended with tenant ID, but while testing IDP initiated SSO it fails.

**[IDP initiated SSO fails with OKTA as an IDP in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62956315/idp-initiated-sso-fails-with-okta-as-an-idp-in-azure)**